Multiline graphical table to seperate lines
I have a (very large) variable width table, something like this:
 1                                 
-----------------                    
 2  | 3  |  4   |                    
    |    | ---- |                     
    |    |  5   |                    
    |    | ---- |                     
    |    |  6   |                   
----------------------------------------
 7  | 8  |  10  | 13 |  14  |    17    |
    | -- | ---- |    | ---- | -------- |
    | 9  | this |    |  15  |    18    |
    |    | is   |    |      |          |
    |    | box  |    |      |          |
    |    |  11! |    |      |          |
    |    | ---- |    | ---- | -------- |
    |    |  12  |    |  16  |  box 19  |
                |    |      | (wider!) |
                |    |      | -------- |
                |           |   20     |
                |           | -------- |
                |           |   21     |
                |           |          |
                |           |          |

I would like to have a linear table, something like this:
 1                                 
-----------------                    
 2                      
                         
                        
                         
                       
||||
 3  
    
    
    
    
|||||||
  4   
 ---- 
  5   
 ---- 
  6   
----------------------------------------
 7  
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
||||
 8  
 --    
 9     
       
       
       
       
       
|||||||
  10  
 ---- 
 this 
 is   
 box  
  11! 
 ---- 
  12  
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
||||||
13 
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
||||
   14  
  ---- 
   15  
       
       
       
  ---- 
   16  
       
       
       
       
       
       
       
||||||||||
    17    
 -------- 
    18    
          
          
          
 -------- 
  box 19  
 (wider!) 
 -------- 
   20     
 -------- 
   21     
          
          

Is there any good way to do this? The only thing I can think of is individually capturing each column with visual block and pasting them at the end of the file; but the table is very large (1000s of boxes) so I don't really want to do that manually. There are a variety of separators which have different meanings (ie more than just -|), so if possible I'd like the separators remain intact

I've never seen either syntax before; if they belong to standard formats, perhaps there's a parser you can use to transform one into the other with a program?

@D.BenKnoble I doubt either one is a 'standard format', it's just a file that I have sitting on my computer that I've made. what would you used to write such a parser?

Well, I'd probably try to write the "rules" of the format down, and then see what I could bang out with my favorite programming language /shrug. That would help improve the question, too: it's not clear to me how to go from parts of the first document to parts of the second.

They're read top-to-bottom within their own columns, and the unbroken horizontal lines separate 'sections'
